# Denoising Autoenoders with Variable Length Input

Tags: neural-network, preprocessing

I'm working on a problem with data from a continuous real-valued signal. The goal is to use ML to smooth the signal based off of past data. To accomplish this, the signal is windowed into a period that's meaningful within the domain. The problem is that this period is highly variable in length.

I've reviewed [this question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/2673/training-neural-networks-with-unknown-length-of-input?rq=1) and [this question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/595/how-to-use-neural-networks-with-large-and-variable-number-of-inputs?rq=1) and neither solve the problem, they are more about how to deal with missing values.

Seeing as denoising autoencoders are based off of matrix multiplication, this presents a serious problem. What is the standard approach in such a situation? Should I define an arbitrary (large) window size, and expand windows that are too small (and vice versa)? Or is there a better approach for variable length inputs?

Comment: How many bins of sizes are there  ?

Comment: Potentially limitless.

Comment: You *might* be able to re-frame your problem using an RNN or some variant, then use a small window working sequentially. But it is not a subject area I know much about. I searched for uses of RNNs as signal denoisers, and found this: http://www1.icsi.berkeley.edu/~vinyals/Files/rnn_denoise_2012.pdf

Comment: I think we might need more information on the data, maybe you could normalise time if that was appropriate, maybe you could bin sequences into a variety of fixed lengths  , maybe there are features of the signal that  are discriminative and relatively independent of time?

Comment: I've tried working with time-independent features with mixed results, and I wanted to see if there were any techniques for handling the irregular periodicity so I could work in the time domain.

Comment: This question should be closed as opinion based _What is the standard approach in such a situation?_ and the accepted answer is a link-only answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recurrent Neural Networks can deal with variable length data. You might want to have a look at:

- Andrej Karpathy: [The Unreasonable Effectiveness of Recurrent Neural Networks](http://karpathy.github.io/2015/05/21/rnn-effectiveness/).
- Christopher Olah: [Understanding LSTM Networks](http://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/).
- Hochreiter, Schmidthuber: [Long short-term memory](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/freeabs_all.jsp?arnumber=6795963).

Another idea (which I have not tested so far and  just came to my mind) is using a histogram approach: You could probably make fixed-size windows, get the data from those windows and make it discrete (e.g. vector quantization, k-means). After that, you can make a histogram of how often those vectors appeared.

You could also use [HMMs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_Markov_model) for recognition of variable length data.

Transformations (e.g. [Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform) from the time domain in the [frequency domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_domain)) might also come in handy.